# Creating a macro in HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to create a web page which redirects a user to a log in page and automatically signs them in using a single log in which I have. (I do not want them to have this log in information - I just want it done automatically).

I have created the macro using VBA and it works there. I wanted to know if there is anyway of implementing this in my HTML code or will I have to re-write the macro in another coding language?

The VBA code I have is:

```
Sub Test()

    Const cURL = "http://www.google.com" 'Enter the web address here
    Const cUsername = "user1" 'Enter your user name here
    Const cPassword = "*****" 'Enter your Password here

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
    Dim UserNameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
    Dim SignInButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
    Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate cURL

    'Wait for initial page to load

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Set doc = IE.Document

    'Get the only form on the page

    Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

    'Get the User Name textbox and populate it
    'input name="Email" id="Email" size="18" value="" class="gaia le val" type="text"

    Set UserNameInputBox = LoginForm.elements("user")
    UserNameInputBox.Value = cUsername

    'Get the password textbox and populate it
    'input name="Passwd" id="Passwd" size="18" class="gaia le val" type="password"


    Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("pass")
    PasswordInputBox.Value = cPassword

    'Get the form input button and click it
    'input class="gaia le button" name="signIn" id="signIn" value="Sign in" type="submit"

    Set SignInButton = LoginForm.elements("LOG_ON_BTN")
    SignInButton.Click

    'Wait for the new page to load

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    End Sub
```

If anyone knows how to implement macros in html that would great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html does have some macro support, but not the kind you're looking for (http://metahtml.sourceforge.net/examples/defining-macros.mhtml)

As html is a markup language and therefore will not be able to do the redirect. If you use MVC to build your website, the desired behavior is easy to achieve.

If you don't use MVC you'll have to go for ASP.Net and rewrite your macro to c# or vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language. It does not possess the necessary structures for programming.

If you are serving the pages with ASP (classic ASP) I think you can use `VBA` or a very similar variant of it. Or adapt your code for `VB.Net` and use `ASP.NET`.

Comment: Could any tell me how to convert this code to C# as I am now using ASP.Net to create the website?